# Android toast not showing

Tags: android, android-location

I have an activity that uses the location of the user. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
public class VolSaveLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                useLocation();    
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.volsavelocaction);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String phoneNumber = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location not null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 0;
            msg.obj = location;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location is null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Problem is, neither of the toasts that are in the onLocationChanged method is displayed. I'm using geo fix to change the location. I have the other methods of LocationListener implemented, but they are empty. The toast to display the phone number is working fine. Can someone help me out?

Comment: put a log in your "onLocationChanged", and see if it even getting invoked.

Comment: there is no 100% percent surety that onLocationChanged call everytime.

Answer (score 0):

One suggetion:

Choose a sensible value for **Timeinterval(2nd parameter of requestLocationUpdates() )**. It is also important to conserve battery life. Each location update requires power from GPS, WIFI, Cell and other radios.

> Select a Time value as high as possible.

Answer (score 0):

on oncreate define a method like getLocation() and in that function write following code

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);      
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);         
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 40000, 1, this);
        if(location!=null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: It is showing three errors:  
1)Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Provider (on the getBestProvider line)  
2)The method getLastKnownLocation(String) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (Provider) and  
3)The method requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (Provider, int, int, 
 VolSaveLocation)  
I think all of these would be fixed if we fix the first error. Could you help me out here? I'm a beginner to android.

Comment: wat data type you defined for provider?? 
And define getLocation() on onCreate part.

Comment: I've defined getLocation and called it from the onCreate method. And I just declared provider as Provider. I didn't know there were different types.

Comment: Provider provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(critera,false);

Comment: Never mind, it worked when I changed NETWORK_PROVIDER into GPS_PROVIDER. Thanks anyway!!